# Anyone know how to get mod_rewrite to include file extensions in its rule?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My rewite rules are:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [NC]
```

The URL http://example.com/home/test/b will return  the internal equivalent ofindex.php?a=home&b=test&c=b. Although this is great (I posted on here yesterday trying to get mod_rewrite to work), I would like to make a url like http://example.com/home/test/b.php to internally call  index.php?a=home&b=test&c=b.php, instead of having Apache trying to find (unsuccessfully) /var/www/home/test/b.php. I would like to have my rewrite rule actually handle all of the file extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w.]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([\w.]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/([\w.]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L,QSA]
```

`[\w.]` in a character class will allow `[a-zA-Z0-9._]`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to handle file extensions, you can do it manually, by changing your last line with :

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/([A-Za-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z]+)?)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [NC]
```

By adding `(\.[a-z]+)?` ,this would handle `http://example.com/home/test/b.php` and then give you, with a `var_dump($_GET);` in `index.php` :

```
array(3) { ["a"]=> string(4) "home" ["b"]=> string(4) "test" ["c"]=> string(5) "b.php" }
```

Hope it helps.

Note : It would only handle one `.`, having at least one `[a-z]` after it.

If you want to handle something like `http://example.com/home/test/b.test.php`, you would need :

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/([A-Za-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z]+)*)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [NC]
```